# Load balancing issue with pgpool2 and postgresql-8.3

Tags: ubuntu, load-balancing, cluster, database-administration, postgresql

I'm using the latest release of pgpool2 on Ubuntu 8.04 with postgres 8.3.11.  Replication is working great, but none of my SELECT queries are being load balanced to my secondary server.  These are just standard SELECT queries. They aren't doing anything special that would prevent them from being balanced, as far as I know.

Here are the relevant settings from my pgpool.conf file:

```
replication_mode = true
load_balance_mode = true
master_slave_mode = false
connection_cache = true
parallel_mode = false

backend_hostname0 = '123.45.67.890'
backend_port0 = 5432
backend_weight0 = 1
backend_data_directory0 = '/var/lib/postgresql/8.3/main'
backend_hostname1 = '123.45.67.891'
backend_port1 = 5432
backend_weight1 = 1
backend_data_directory1 = '/var/lib/postgresql/8.3/main'
```

Here's an example of a query from my pgpool.log while I had pgpool running in debug mode: http://dpaste.com/212865/

I'm assuming I've got a misconfiguration somwhere.  I'd greatly appreciate any help in tracking it down.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing this problem using the latest version of pgpool2 compiled from source.  I reverted to the version of pgpool2 present in the Ubuntu 8.04 repos, and load balancing is now working.  I assume this must be a bug in the latest release.